# block a particular number?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I want to block few mobile numbers from my application.

I mean can receive the blocked mobile number call or message... but want it rejected right away, without the phone ringing.

Is it possible to do this from my application? If it is, please give me some samples..

```
 Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
 Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
 m.setAccessible(true);
 telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
 telephonyService.silenceRinger();
 telephonyService.endCall();
 } catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@venkat goto this http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/ link it provide working sorce code to block o/g calls and also tested by me.

Comment: is it works for emulator... i want to block only one number how is it?

Comment: dude i am using this in my working application means on live project now want to say anything ?

Comment: i try the same code for two emulator but it is not working what wrong with me?

Comment: i copy the same code and executed with out any modifications but it gives me nothing???

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904426/how-to-block-a-mobile-number-call-and-message-receiving-in-android-application-d/9904826#9904826 i just give source to prasad