# How to block a mobile number call and message receiving in android application development?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, blocking, phone-call

I would like to implement an application for block a mobile number for receiving or sending calls and messages. In my application I am entering mobile number at `EditText` box then I am clicking a button for block the mobile number which has entered by the user.

I have implemented an activity class as follows:

```
public class BlockNumberActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.block)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String mobileNumer = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobileNum)).getText().toString();
                //How to block entered mobileNumber
            }
        });

        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.unblock)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String mobileNumer = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobileNum)).getText().toString();
                //How to unblock entered mobileNumber
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I think we may use `BroadcastReceiver`. But I don't have more knowledge on it. Please give me an idea how to implement blocking or unblocking mobile number.
Please any body help me.....

Comment: Try to see this [BlockIncoming Messages](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9378431/940096) & [Block Incoming Calls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2334465/940096)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

create **PhoneCallReceiver .java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {  

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    PhoneCallStateListener customPhoneListener = new PhoneCallStateListener(context);
    telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);



}}
```

**now create PhoneCallStateListener .java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;

public class PhoneCallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {    

private Context context;
public PhoneCallStateListener(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {  
    SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    switch (state) {

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:       

              String block_number = prefs.getString("block_number", null);
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
            //Turn ON the mute
            audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);                 
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            try {
                Toast.makeText(context, "in"+block_number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Class clazz = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
                Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                method.setAccessible(true);
                ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);     
                //Checking incoming call number
                System.out.println("Call "+block_number);

                if (incomingNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("+91"+block_number)) {
                    //telephonyService.silenceRinger();//Security exception problem
                     telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);
                     telephonyService.silenceRinger();
                    System.out.println(" in  "+block_number);
                    telephonyService.endCall();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            //Turn OFF the mute     
            audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
            break;
        case PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE:

    }
    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
}}
```

Now in src create this **package** `com.android.internal.telephony` **now in this package Right Click ->  New -> File now give name `ITelephony.aidl` and paste this code**

```
package com.android.internal.telephony; 

interface ITelephony {      

  boolean endCall();     

  void answerRingingCall();      

  void silenceRinger(); 
}
```

**NOTE:** Code is tested in Android 2.2 (Froyo),2.3 (GingerBread)

Comment: how can i execute PhoneCallStateListener class in my app.I mean how it will execute?

Comment: insyead this u can specify this  String block_number = "10 digit number";

Comment: i am not getting incoming number at if(incomingNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("+91"+block_number))

Comment: what ? String block_number = "10 digit number" and now u can use my above coding

Comment: i am not getting incoming number at if(incomingNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("5555215556")).i am asking for incomingNumber variable.

Comment: there is no value for incomingNumber for comparing with my 10 digit number

Comment: use country code like if(incomingNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("+91"+"5555215556")) ;

Comment: hey i am not getting incomingNumber value for comparring with "+91"+"5555215556"

Comment: not possible , use in device coz i am using this source in my app.

Comment: @Rstar BZZZZTTTT!!!! your code will certainly not work for ICS/JB and later because Google has blocked the MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission since Gingerbread and thus will fail when invoking `endCall` or `cancelMissedCallsNotification` of the ITelephony type interface! See this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15031) Otherwise feel free to prove me wrong on this! :)

Comment: @Rstar What permissions are required for this? And the intent-filter to use with the `BroadcastReceiver`. Also, does this work on ICS and Jellybean?

Comment: @Rstar Okay, I tested your code on my device. It seems it's working except for the `silenceRinger()` function which requires the `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission.

Comment: why but i'm getting `NoSuchMethodException` at ` Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");` ??

Answer (score 3):

to block incoming call use this http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html and also this http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/333253/Block-Incoming-calls-in-android-without-single-rin ,http://www.anddev.org/post52643.html?hilit=incoming%20call#p52643 or to block outgoing see [How to Block outgoing calls and Text SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595092/how-to-block-outgoing-calls-and-text-sms) and [Blocking outgoing calls and texts (BroadcastReceiver or Service?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735287/blocking-outgoing-calls-and-texts-broadcastreceiver-or-service) , [Android: Taking complete control of phone(kiosk mode), is it possible? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121508/android-taking-complete-control-of-phone-is-it-possible-how/7121586#7121586)

Comment: i would like block a mobile number which has entered by the user only

Answer (score 2):

This Code works for me

```
  try {

            String serviceManagerName = "android.os.ServiceManager";
            String serviceManagerNativeName = "android.os.ServiceManagerNative";
            String telephonyName = "com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony";
            Class<?> telephonyClass;
            Class<?> telephonyStubClass;
            Class<?> serviceManagerClass;
            Class<?> serviceManagerNativeClass;
            Method telephonyEndCall;
            Object telephonyObject;
            Object serviceManagerObject;
            telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephonyName);
            telephonyStubClass = telephonyClass.getClasses()[0];
            serviceManagerClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerName);
            serviceManagerNativeClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerNativeName);
            Method getService =
                    serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
            Method tempInterfaceMethod = serviceManagerNativeClass.getMethod(
                    "asInterface", IBinder.class);
            Binder tmpBinder = new Binder();
            tmpBinder.attachInterface(null, "fake");
            serviceManagerObject = tempInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, tmpBinder);
            IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(
                    serviceManagerObject, "phone");
            Method serviceMethod = telephonyStubClass.getMethod("asInterface",
                    IBinder.class);
            telephonyObject = serviceMethod.invoke(null, retbinder);
            telephonyEndCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("endCall");
            telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to Block Call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To block a call of any specific contact number, then this tutorial will help you in solving your problem.
http://androiddesk.wordpress.com/2012/08/02/blocking-a-call-without-user-intervention-in-android/

Answer (score -1):

this code is working...

first download this class [ITelephony](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.java)

```
if ((state != null)
                && (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))) {
            CallLogReceiver.phoneNo = intent.getExtras().getString(
                    "incoming_number");

            if (CallLogReceiver.blockNo.equals(CallLogReceiver.phoneNo)) {

                Intent blockCallIntent = new Intent();
                blockCallIntent.setClassName("com.example.calllogdemo",
                        "com.example.calllogdemo.BlockCallActivity");
                blockCallIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                blockCallIntent
                        .putExtra("blockNo", CallLogReceiver.phoneNo);
                context.startActivity(blockCallIntent);
                try {
                    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                    Class<?> classTelephony = Class
                            .forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
                    Method methodGetITelephony = classTelephony
                            .getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");

                    methodGetITelephony.setAccessible(true);

                    ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony)         methodGetITelephony
                            .invoke(telephonyManager);

                    telephonyService.endCall();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

and use this permission in manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```