# I want to create an app that will block unwanted phonecalls in android phones?

Tags: android

Is it possible to create an app that will block  unwanted phonecalls in android phones?
Like  [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netqin.mm&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5uZXRxaW4ubW0iXQ..)

Any specific api for this and guidelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buddy goto [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9904826/1218762) , here you will get how to block incoming calls.just follow my code.