# how to catch and block unknown incoming calls

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a problem. My receiver is run very succesfull but when on private numbers not work my code.

```
private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        Log.d("MyPhoneListener", state + "   incoming no:" + incomingNumber);

        if (state == 1) {

            Cursor numaralar = NumaralariGetir();

            while (numaralar.moveToNext()) {

                String numara = numaralar.getString(numaralar
                        .getColumnIndex("numara"));
                if (incomingNumber.equals(numara)) { // DialedNumber
                                                        // checking.
                    abortBroadcast();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See below link :-

[how to block a mobile number call and message receiving in android application development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904426/how-to-block-a-mobile-number-call-and-message-receiving-in-android-application-d/9904826#9904826)

http://blog.wangling.me/2009/08/why-it-is-impossible-to-intercept-incoming-calls-on-android.html

Comment: thanks for help but when my phone get private numbers, my app is stopp. :/