# How to block incoming calls from unknown numbers programmatically?

Tags: android, call, block

I want to create an app that blocks all numbers that are not in contacts.
I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407358/how-to-catch-and-block-unknown-incoming-calls)  but it is not perfect.
How to do this? Thanks for reading

Comment: What you have tried to code yet?

Comment: i try this: telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm); 

      telephonyService.silenceRinger(); 
      telephonyService.endCall();

Comment: but i don't know how to block unknown number

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to use it. First, you have to use ITelephony in your project. I will give you an example to use it in below link. Second, you have to insert code to start service when you restart phone as follows:

in AndroidManifest File :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Change this to :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,BackgroundService.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);
    }
```

The sample code at https://github.com/Levon-Petrosyan/Call_redirect_and_reject