# TelephonyManager unable to return phone number in android

Tags: java, android

I'm implementing a payment app. So for contact verification I have to find the contact number. Also i'm sending a sms from sim for cross verification on server. I have tried

```
> TelephonyManager tm =
> (TelephonyManager)this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
> String phoneNumber=  tm.getLine1Number();
```

but I'm unable to get contact number. I have also implemented broadcast receiver to check weather sms sent or delivered. So is there any way to get the contact number or not?

Comment: check this link
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904426/how-to-block-a-mobile-number-call-and-message-receiving-in-android-application-d>. its helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined this permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Also use `getActivity().getApplicationContext();` in place of `this.getApplicationContext()` if you are using fragment

Comment: Yes I have already define the permission in manifest file. And this solution not working. @kgandroid

Comment: where have you written your code??activity or fragment??