# Can not resolve symbol ITelephony

Tags: java, android, package, aidl

I would like to block call from specific number I tried some solution but I get errors.
I tried this solution but it is not working.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9904826/1937692
It gives

> Can not resolve symbol ITelephony

Project Structure:

http://i.hizliresim.com/P02XOd.png

PhoneCallReceiver:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        PhoneCallStateListener customPhoneListener = new PhoneCallStateListener(context);
        telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


    }}
```

ITelephony.aidl:

```
package com.android.internal.telephony;

interface ITelephony {

  boolean endCall();

  void answerRingingCall();

  void silenceRinger();
}
```

PhoneCallStateListener:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony; //Error Line

    public class PhoneCallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        private Context context;
        public PhoneCallStateListener(Context context){
            this.context = context;
        }


        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

            switch (state) {

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                    String block_number = prefs.getString("block_number", null);
                    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    //Turn ON the mute
                    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
                    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "in"+block_number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Class clazz = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
                        Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                        method.setAccessible(true);
                        ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager); //Error Line
                        //Checking incoming call number
                        System.out.println("Call "+block_number);

                        if (incomingNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("+91"+block_number)) {
                            //telephonyService.silenceRinger();//Security exception problem
                            telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);
                            telephonyService.silenceRinger();
                            System.out.println(" in  "+block_number);
                            telephonyService.endCall();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    //Turn OFF the mute
                    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
                    break;
                case PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE:

            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }}
```

Error - Red Lines:
http://i.hizliresim.com/YD8zQA.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface `ITelephony` is package-visible and therefore not accessible from outside of the package `com.android.internal.telephony`.

That's because it is an internal Android API.

Answer (score 0):

you have added **ITelephony.AIDL** file in your project? and if you have added then your package name must be **com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.AIDL**: for more information [Blocking Incoming call](http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/). download AIDL file from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.java)